# Enviar datos de javascript a PHP

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda, estoy intentando enviar datos desde js a php, pero no me reconoce los datos cuando intento mandarlos php.

```
fetch('http://localhost/PHP/Raw%20Material/public/scripts/php/createRequest.php', {
    method: 'post',
    body: {arrJson:arrJson}
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Pero si lo hago con Jquery si lo toma

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'http://localhost/PHP/Raw%20Material/public/scripts/php/createRequest.php', 
   data:{arrJson:arrJson},
   success:function(datos){
       console.log(datos)
   }
})
```

y no quiero jquery ya que tengo puro codigo en javascript y no me gustaria mezclar, este es el array

```
let requestor = document.getElementById('REQUESTOR').value
let departament = document.getElementById('DEPARTAMENT').value

let data = {
    requestor: requestor,
    departament: departament
}

let arrJson = JSON.stringify(data)
```

Edit:

```
<?php

    $datos = json_decode( $_POST['arrJson'], true );

    foreach( $datos as $valor ){
        echo 'Objeto: '.$valor;
    }

?>
```

Comment: ¿No será esto?  `body: JSON.stringify({requestor: requestor})`... tendriamos que ver el php que lo recibe para verificar que datos espera, pues en el jquery envias `arrJson` con dos datos, no uno

Comment: Disculpa, me equivoque, no puse el actualizado ya que estaba haciendo pruebas pero ya lo edite asi como muestras, ademas edite el post y coloque la parte de php, que es algo basico, recibo el array, lo recorro y voy imprimiendo, pero con el fetch no llega a php, es lo raro

Comment: Y ahora que lo veo, ¿no sera por las **minúsculas** de `post` en el fetch?  Prueba con `method: 'POST',` ... y si no es eso metele un `print_r($_POST);` al principio del php a ver que sale, si sale algo

Comment: [Segun veo](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-method) tiene que ser eso de las mayúsculas en el parámetro `method`, pues si que distingue entre minúsculas y mayúsculas, por lo tanto usa POST en mayúsculas

Comment: Ya gregue **POST** en mayusculas y nada, sin embargo si hago el print post en php, usando jquery `Array ( [arrJson] => {"requestor":"sadd","departament":"SCP"} )` pero si lo hago con fetch solo me devuelve `Array()`

Comment: Pues haz un `console.log(arrJson)` antes del fetch y comprueba que le llegan los datos alli

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en el fetch.

```
fetch('http://localhost/PHP/Raw%20Material/public/scripts/php/createRequest.php', {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({arrJson:arrJson})
}).then(function(response){
   console.log(response)
}).then(function(data){
   console.log(data)
});
```

Si te das cuenta te falta el **JSON.stringify** que es para serializar el JSON a un string para mandarlo. También te falta los headers para decirle en la cabecera de la llamada que es tipo JSON lo que mandas.

En el archivo PHP creo que te falta lo siguiente al principio de todo.

```
<?php
  // Toma datos sin procesar de la solicitud
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

  // Lo convierte en un objeto PHP
  $datos = json_decode($json);
  echo $datos;
?>
```

Asi coges el Json que te viene del post y lo conviertes a un objeto.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Ya agregue la linea de los headers, y en el tercer pedazo de los codigos que agregue ahi sale donde esta el **JSON.stringify** , `let arrJson = JSON.stringify(data)` , pero aun asi en php no me reconoce el arrJason, `Warning: Undefined array key "arrJson"` , solamente en jquery no tengo ese problema

Comment: @Victor Garcia puede ser que el problema lo tengas en el PHP entonces me he mirado mis proyectos y cuando mando JSon por POST en todos los archivos de php le pongo el file_get_contents para poder leerlo, mira haber si asi te funciona.

Comment: Acabo de agregar la primera al codigo y me sale este error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`, y no creo que el problema venga del PHP ya que si hago lo mismo pero usando JQuery , si me imprime en php los datos, solo por alguna razon con fetch no llegan los datos.